# LDAP get primary group name of a user in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, dsquery

There is a scenario where I need to fetch all the group names for which a particular user is a member of, using LDAP query.
The input will be: users distinguished name 
and the output should be: list of groups for whom this user is a member of.

So far I am able to fetch all the group names a user is member of except the primary group using below LDAP query:

Query:

```
dsquery * "member:LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN:=cn=user1,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Output:

```
"CN=group1,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
"CN=mygroup,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
```

The above query list all the groups "user1" is a member of except the primary group name which is "Domain Admins".

Some how figured out to get primary group RID instead using below LDAP query:

```
dsquery * "cn=user1,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -scope base -attr primaryGroupID
```

But getting group name from group RID is again not working, instead if I would have got the primary group SID then that would be easy to get the group name. But what I am getting is primary group RID from which I am not able to fetch group name using LDAP.

Any help regarding this would be great, any way by which I can get the primary group name using some LDAP query only.

Comment: Please add the [tag:ldap-query] tag to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use *dsget* rather than *dsquery*.  This is how to find all groups for a particular member including nested groups and the primary group:

```
dsget user "cn=user1,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -memberof -expand
```